# jquery load() points second video source, instead of just showing poster

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I've developed on Jquery API for HTML5 Vido. It works fine except a single issue.

Task: Have to show poster image on the end of a video.

Code I've used:

```
$hdVideo.bind('ended', function() {
                $hd_play_btn.removeClass('hd-paused-button');
                $(".hd-video-main-control").removeClass('hd-video-main-control-none');
                $hdVideo.load();
            });
```

Issues: It shows poster on the end of the video. But unfortunatly the second video source starts when play the video again in chrome 13.0.

My HTML code is:

```
<video width="630" height="354" class="hd-flv-player" poster="asserts/poster.png" controls="controls" data-name="demo video" data-uid="57fb2708">
        <source src="http://hdflvplayer.net/hdflvplayer/videos/Casion-Royale-Chase.mp4" data-quality="hd"/>
        <source src="http://static.clipcanvas.com/sample/clipcanvas_14348_offline.mp4" data-quality="sd"/>
        <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" data-quality="hd"/>
        <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" data-quality="sd"/>
</video>
```

JQuery Plugin call code:

```
$(function(){
    var $hdVid = jQuery.noConflict();
    $hdVid(function(){
        $hdVid('.hd-flv-player').hdVideo();
    });
});
```

Please let me know how to fix my bug.

Comment: Could you post the $hdVideo.load() function? The problem might lie in there, as this looks tentatively ok.

Comment: I didn't write any function for $hdVideo.load()
Its predefined jquery libraty function

Comment: So does $hdVideo then refer to a particular <video> element on your page? If so, could you post the HTML?

Comment: <video width="630" height="354" class="hd-flv-player" poster="asserts/poster.png" controls="controls" data-name="demo video" data-uid="57fb2708">
            <source src="http://hdflvplayer.net/hdflvplayer/videos/Casion-Royale-Chase.mp4" data-quality="hd"/>
            <source src="http://static.clipcanvas.com/sample/clipcanvas_14348_offline.mp4" data-quality="sd"/>
            <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" data-quality="hd"/>
            <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" data-quality="sd"/>
 </video>

Comment: the jquery is:
$(function() {
        var $hdVid = jQuery.noConflict();
        $hdVid(function() {
            $hdVid('.hd-flv-player').hdVideo();
        });
    });

Comment: @VelMuruganS Please post additional data on the post itself, not as a comment.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: have updated the question with more information...
hope its enough for you now...

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer awaiting for your help friend